# Replace special characters with sed

Tags: sed

I have to replace special characters using shell, so i use sed but i have some mistakes that i don't understand.

```
<%_ by [@, ("_" = dash)
_%> by ]
```

for the first 2 characters my synthax is : `sed -i y/\<%\/\]\/ test.htm`
it works, but here how can i add the dash character ?
The second should be this way `sed -i y/\%>\/\]\/`
but i have this mistake `bash: /]/: is a folder`
can you help me please

Comment: `_` is underscore, `-` is dash. Which of these do you want to replace?

Comment: You need to quote the `sed` argument that contains the subsitution, because it includes special shell characters.

Comment: And the command to do string substitution is `s/from/to/`. `y` is for doing character-by-character translation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to replace (with a - or _ in the first case) but this works fine for me:

```
$ echo "<%_" | sed 's/<%_/_/'
_
$ echo "<%_" | sed 's/<%_/-/'
-
$ echo "_%>" | sed 's/_%>/\]/'
]
```

It looks like you are escaping the regex identifiers (the /).

Comment: Apparently the only character that needs to be escaped for me is the ], everything else works fine (not special in the regex provided)

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the argument, and use the `s` command to perform string substitution. You can use the `-e` option to supply multiple command expressions.

```
sed -i -e 's/<% /[@/' -e 's/ %>/]/' filename
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but i have a mistake with ']', it's output  bash: /]/: is a folder so i don't understand why. Also you can consider the dash as a space, i did not know how to explain it. In my file it is like this `<% `        and   ` %>`

Comment: You should only get an error like that if you forgot to quote the arguments. An unquoted `>` is used to redirect output of a command.

Comment: finally sed 's/%>/]/g' file