# How can you use sed to replace spaces with periods and still keep () and []

Tags: linux, sed

I want to remove all special characters leaving only A-Za-z0-9.()[]

```
echo 'Some Movie Name! (2015) [1080p]' |sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9.()[]]/./g'
```

Gives me this output:

```
Some Movie Name! (2015) [1080p]
```

This is what I want:

```
Some.Movie.Name.(2015).[1080p]
```

I cant figure out how to escape the "]" "]" doesn't work.

The closest I can get is this:

```
echo 'Some Movie Name! (2015) [1080p]' |sed -e 's/[^A-Za-z0-9.()[]/./g'
Some.Movie.Name..(2015).[1080p.
```

Then I can pipe it to sed again to remove double periods:

```
|sed 's/\.\././g'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace special characters with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196915/replace-special-characters-with-sed)

Comment: Could there be another parenthesis or brackets in the titles? like `'Some Movie Name! [dvdrip] (2015) [1080p]'`

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Glenn Jackman's keen observations the method is changed to the following:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$string" | tr -cs '[:alnum:].[]()\n' '[.*]'
```

- `-c` => invert/complement the input set
- `-s` => will squeeze consecutive characters from the complemented input set found in the data to a single dot character.

Beware there are few implementations of `tr` that support multibyte characters than implementations of `sed` that do. In particular GNU `tr` doesn't while GNU `sed` does, so for that to work on non-English letters with UTF-8 input for instance, you may want to switch to `sed`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$string" | sed 's/[^][[:alnum:]()]\{1,\}/./g'
```

Note that the `]` must come right after the `^`. Also note we remove the `.` from the complemented set so that `foo-.txt` for instance be changed to `foo.txt` instead of `foo..txt` like with `tr`-based solution.

Comment: You don't even need to include the `\n` -- assuming the OP will capture the output in a command substitution, any trailing newlines get removed anyway.

Comment: Oh, I see that the trailing newline is replaced by a dot. In that case, change `echo` to `printf "%s"`, or use a here-string: `tr -cs '[:alnum:].[]()' . <<< 'Some Movie Name! (2015) [1080p]'`

Comment: and I would suggest, for better readability, keep the bracket pairs together: `tr -cs '[:alnum:].[]()' .`

Answer (score 0):

Put the closing `]` you want to match directly after the negation `^` where it is not misinterpreted. You can use `\+` at the end of the regex to replace multiple characters with one period (thanks @Rakesh Sharma):

```
$ echo 'Some Movie Name! (2015) [1080p]' | sed -e 's/[^][A-Za-z0-9()]\+/./g'
Some.Movie.Name.(2015).[1080p]
```

Comment: Also now remove the dot from the list.

Comment: Ah, right, good catch!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with [`tr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html):

```
x='Some Movie Name! (2015) [1080p]'
printf '%s\n' "$x" | tr -cd 'A-Za-z0-9.()[] ' | tr ' ' '.'
Some.Movie.Name.(2015).[1080p]
```

Comment: I've got the feeling that for `some+movie+name` for instance, the OP would want `some.movie.name` rather than `somemoviename`, that is that all sequences of characters other than alnums and `()[]` should be replaced with `.`

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
$ set -o extendedglob
$ string='Some Movie Name! (2015) [1080p]'
$ printf '%s\n' ${string//[^][()[:alnum:]]##/.}
Some.Movie.Name.(2015).[1080p]
```

With `ksh93` or `bash -O extglob` (after `shopt -s extglob` within a bash invocation started without `-O extglob`):

```
$ string='Some Movie Name! (2015) [1080p]'
$ printf '%s\n' "${string//+([^][()[:alnum:]])/.}"
Some.Movie.Name.(2015).[1080p]
```

zsh's `x##` or ksh's `+(x)` is like extended regexp `x+` and matches one or more `x`s.